# Парсинг даты из строки java

Tags: java, строки, дата, datetime, simpledateformat

У меня есть строка "03:54". Как я могу превратить ее в Date по паттерну "mm:ss"? Буду благодарен :)

Comment: Вы хотите превратить время в Date. Тогда какая дата будет установлена? и часы

Answer (score 2):

Для этого в java существует класс SimpleDateFormat.

```
    String time = "03:54";
    String format = "mm:ss";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    Date date = dateFormat.parse(time);
    System.out.println(date);
```

Время будет поставлено корректно, но год и день будет поставлен по-умолчанию, потому что их нет в формате.

Answer (score 1):

При использовании этого кусочка кода:

```
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");
   Date d = sdf.parse("03:54");
   System.out.println(d);
```

вы получите 1 января 1970 года, по этому предварительно вам нужный вам текст, все же нужно дополнять нужной же датой, или же выполнять передвигание полученной даты, на сегодняшнюю - это уже на любителя)